getMultipleAccountsInfoAndContext unable to find owner of a token account
I'm using web3.js to retrieve the top holders of a token by using getTokenLargestAccounts, everything works fine and I'm able to retrieve holders and perform some calculations to determine the holders percentage.
After retrieving the accounts address, I'm using getMultipleAccountsInfoAndContext to fetch the information about the token account holders, my goal here is to check if the account is owned by Raydium Authority V4 and so the amount is in the liquidity pool.
Here is the code I'm using:
        // Fetch total token supply
        const tokenSupplyResponse = await solanaConnection.getTokenSupply(vault);
        const tokenSupply = tokenSupplyResponse.value.uiAmount != null ? tokenSupplyResponse.value.uiAmount : 0;

        // Fetch token account balances for all accounts holding the token
        const tokenAccountsResponse = await solanaConnection.getTokenLargestAccounts(vault);
        const tokenAccounts = tokenAccountsResponse.value;

        // Extract public keys of the top holder accounts
        const topHolderPublicKeys = tokenAccounts.map(account => account.address);

        // Fetch account information for the top holder accounts
        const accountsInfoResponse = await solanaConnection.getMultipleAccountsInfoAndContext(topHolderPublicKeys);
        const accountsInfo = accountsInfoResponse.value;

        // Array to store top holders with additional information
        const topHolders: { address: string; percentage: number; owner: Owner}[] = [];

        // Calculate percentage of total supply held by each account and add to topHolders array
        for (let i = 0; i < tokenAccounts.length; i++) {
            const account = tokenAccounts[i];
            const accountInfo = accountsInfo[i];

            if (account.uiAmount !== null && accountInfo !== null) {
                const percentage: number = (account.uiAmount / tokenSupply) * 100;
                topHolders.push({
                    address: account.address.toBase58(),
                    percentage,
                    owner:  accountInfo.owner
                });
            }
        }

        // Sort topHolders array by percentage in descending order
        topHolders.sort((a, b) => b.percentage - a.percentage);

The issue is that the for every checked account the returned owner is always TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Here is a sample output
    0: {
          "address": "En4SGPjP7U7juqMpwkTubrBcNwdrpHJuyhUbWV2vazvZ",
          "percentage": 89.99491303789999,
          "owner": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
        }
        1: {
          "address": "E4QguyBEt32X2tFCKFBVhMMwPTfjsLEaKjK1KKnnBZoE",
          "percentage": 10,
          "owner": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
        }
        2: {
          "address": "EgPjzwzudaWGg4rZN24SCFDrvYi5boXfx6iruJaXsy7T",
          "percentage": 0.0029923208,
          "owner": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
        }

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Maybe there is another method to verify what I want to check? Thanks
